# Will it be allowed if I took help from tutorials to make portfolio projects and made websites clone?

Tags: halal-haram

Will my income be hallal if I get a job in software field by showing portfolio projects that I have developed by following the tutorials from internet. The hiring process does not consist of only showing portfolio there is an interview. And if I do get the job I will be getting paid for the work I am doing. I don’t know the expectation of person hiring from portfolio if it is that I developed all my projects all myself without any tutorials from internet or just to know my skills.
Similarly, if I make portfolio projects that implement the functionality of existing website. For example making a youtube or twitter clone without taking content from original website to demonstrate my skills. Will that have same problems as stated above or is that allowed. Websites have copyright issues sometimes but I will not take the images or other content from websites I am making a clone of and it is not an actual competitor or any thing just a demo project.

clarifications:
In software field people take help from other peoples code.so lets say i am developing a feature that is new for me and i will search for blog posts or youtube videos like how to implement xyz in so and so language etc and then implement the blog post or youtube solution into my project.People think this is fine as you are modifying the original and the help taken is just the part of your project not the whole project and the person posting the solution intends to share it with others. so i was confused about this practice.
Secondly, newcomers make projects like youtube clone, twitter clone etc i.e. write code to make a youtube like website for portfolio project. Now if you don't use the content from youtube or twitter are you fine or not. The companies most likely don't care about such student projects but copyright laws are complex so could that impact my income if make such a project.

Comment: Like any library, Islam Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice or legal verdicts, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your Mufti, Imam, or other trustworthy Counselor.

Comment: In order to answer your question you must reflect the following: What do you think is illegal and why? I miss an explicit explanation. Please consider editing your post and adding all relevant information.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I tried adding some clarifications. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are worried about correctness of following two situations. Please correct me if I have not understood it correctly.

> ...if I get a job in software field by showing portfolio projects that I have developed by following the tutorials from internet.

and

> I make portfolio projects that implement the functionality of existing website...

The key question in both cases is, **is there any deception involved?**

Learn from tutorials. Make your profile. Link the tutorial you have followed prominently. In fact, learning from tutorials is a great way to develop your skills.

Preparing a clone of an existing project should not be a problem either as long as no deception is involved. Of course you need to be careful about copyright issues.

**Note:** In case you are down-voting my answer, you are most welcome. Please leave a comment explaining your down-vote. I will debate your reasoning. The reason I am adding this note is - I have received multiple unexplained down-votes in past on this forum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.